# How do I kill the Xinopherydon?

Tags: candy-box-2

I fly in with my rocket boots and can't kill it before it kills me - it's got 5000 HP and hits really hard (500HP a go).  I keep dying.

Answer (score 1):

Use Anti-gravity potions and jumping to get close enough to the Xinopherydon to use ranged attacks, and the Boots of Introspection to ensure you don't get too close.

Ranged attacks might be Acid rain, fireballs or magic balls.

Answer (score 1):

From the [wiki](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Xinopherydon):

> The best way to kill a Xinopherydon is to equip the [Rocket Boots](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Rocket_Boots) and the [Monkey Wizard Staff](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Monkey_Wizard_Staff) (or even better, the enchanted version). Then fly over to the room below the Xinopherydon and spam [black demons](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Black_magic_grimoire) (if you have that spell).
>
> The Xinopherydon has 5,000 health and only uses melee attacks, so no magic. Upon killing, it drops 30,000 candies and the [Xinopherydon claw](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Xinopherydon_claw).

Comment: Using the monkey wand you can just stand under him and wait. The black demons... eh. I found that the monkey wand didn't take too long. So they weren't really necessary.